# Apache2 not working after changing the default port

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

Apache2 is not working after changing the default port from 80  to 8099

I did the following:

In /etc/apache2/ports.conf, changed the port to:

```
Listen 8099
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf, did this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8099>
```

Then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I tried to check the ports that are open using: sudo netstat -plunt, here is the outcome:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1179/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1005/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::8099                 :::*                    LISTEN      6337/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1005/sshd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:14717           0.0.0.0:*                           641/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           641/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::48002                :::*                                641/dhclient
```

anything I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like 8099 is listening, it's right there in the netstat output...

Answer (score 1):

Seems it works but strangely for IPv6 only.

Here is a way to force it to use IPv4: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237610

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8099
```

Comment: Does `netstat -na | grep 8099.*LIST` still show tcp6 after that change?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the bold portions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    #ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/'Your folder acess'/public
    <Directory /var/www/'Your folder acess'/public>   
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>   
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined  
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Fine mr.Sharma. apache2 is working on only default port of 8080. So donot change it or else it not working. Follow  a reinstall steps of apache2.